# switch from transparent to black text

Tags: beamer, transparency

Following use of `\newtheorem`, the subsequent text turns transparent for reasons that I can't understand.  Since I can't find the source of this problem, I'd just like to try a second-best fix by telling `beamer` to switch from transparent text to black text.  What is the relevant command?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usetheme[height=9mm]{Rochester} 
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball] 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{ } 
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered] 
\usepackage{pgfpages} 
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[letterpaper,border shrink=-4mm,landscape] 
\begin{document}
 \newtheorem*{hyp*}{Empirical Hypothesis} 
\begin{frame}
 \begin{hyp*}
 This is my empirical hypothesis \end{hyp*} This additional text is transparent. 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us a minimal code producing the problem.

Comment: I edited the post to you. You can delete your comment above.

Comment: Your code works fine here. No problem.

Comment: Thanks @sigur, but it doesn't work on my system, for reasons that are unclear.  So I'd like to fix the problem by just telling Beamer to switch from transparent text to black text.  What command(s) should I use.

Comment: There is no command to do this. You have some other problems. Try to update the `beamer` class.

Comment: You can try `\normalfont`, but I'd suggest you use `\listfiles` to get the version of each of the package used and post it here. Probably some package just needs to be updated.

Comment: Try `\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text} This additional text is transparent.` to switch back to the normal text colour. Nevertheless it would be interesting what the real problem is, so could you add which versions of the packages etc. you are using?

Comment: Thanks, samcarter.  That suggestion works for one frame, and then transparent text returns on the next frame.  \color{black} also works, but needs to be repeated each frame.  I'm using PCTeX, an integrated package that has an old 2005 beamer.cls file (some people say that's the issue).  But this problem wasn't present before I upgraded to Windows 7 and reinstalled everything.  It remains a mystery.